# PHP Response to HTTP Request From Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, post, response

I've searched alot to find a way to send HTTP Response to Android Application that sends HTTP Request with Username and Password

My problem is I want to take the username and password from android application and send back the values for that user from 3 columns (toggle1,toggle2,toggle3) in the database

All examples I've seen now  only send 1 or 0 just for checking username and password if it's correct or not but I need  to send also Columns Data from Database, I Prefer it's not JSON

Activity that sends HTTP Request and Also reads data

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpLogin extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button login;
    private EditText username, password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String   mUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String  mPassword = password.getText().toString();

                tryLogin(mUsername, mPassword);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void tryLogin(String mUsername, String mPassword)
    {           
        HttpURLConnection connection;
       OutputStreamWriter request = null;

            URL url = null;   
            String response = null;         
            String parameters = "username="+mUsername+"&password="+mPassword;   

            try
            {
                url = new URL("your login URL");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write(parameters);
                request.flush();
                request.close();            
                String line = "";               
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.                
                response = sb.toString();
                // You can perform UI operations here
                Toast.makeText(this,"Message from Server: \n"+ response, 0).show();             
                isr.close();
                reader.close();

            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                // Error
            }
    }
}
```

PHP File That Receives username and password and I need this file to also send database Columns values for the username and password

```
<?php   
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$user="test"; // Mysql username 
$pswd="123"; // Mysql password 
$db="pet_home"; // Database name 
//$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$result=mysql_query("select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'")or die (mysql_error());
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);    
        if ($count > 0){
        echo 1;     
        }else{
        echo 0;
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you want will be in the $row array. You can access them (depending on the column you want) like this $row[0], $row[1], etc.

It looks like the response currently is just the echo'd value 0 or 1

Why not just append them to that string separated by an uncommon character like the pipe or asterisk then split it back up?

Your echo then would be something like

```
echo 1."|".$row[0]."|".$row[1];
```

etc.

** Also, I should add the obigitory "hash your passwords and consider security"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 try{
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }catch(Exception e){
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                 }
```